# GUI Buttons clicking when i first start game

Tags: javascript

Im trying to make a menu screen for my game, and i set up my buttons in the same way as the manual http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/gui-Basics.html

when i open my game the button clicked code runs as soon as I loads`#pragma strict

```
var guiSkin : GUISkin;
private var Options : boolean;
var OptionsGUI : GameObject;
var MenuGUI : GameObject;

function Start ()
{

}
function OnGUI()
{
    GUI.Box(Rect(200, 360, 400, 75)," ");
    GUI.skin = guiSkin;
    GUI.Button(Rect(200, 135, 400, 75),"P L A Y");
    if(GUI.Button(Rect(200, 210, 400, 75),"O P T I O N S"));
    {
        SetOptions();
    }
    GUI.Button(Rect(200, 285, 400, 75),"I N S T R U C T I O N S");
    GUI.Button(Rect(200, 360, 400, 75),"A B O U T");
}
function SetOptions ()
{   
    OptionsGUI.GetComponent(options).enabled = true;
    MenuGUI.GetComponent(menu).enabled = false;
}`
```

The OptionsGUI opens up several GUI for my options screen

Comment: Perhaps you need to read this article first: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Looks like you're mixing Javascript and C#(?). The syntax at the top is not Javascript. If you are using another language, please add that as a tag. Also, if it's compiling the Javascript, post the compiled Javascript from the source.

Comment: I don't see any C# in there, i only use java script, could you point out what could be identified as C#?